# Fading UIView allows subviews to be seen

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview, alpha

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains various subviews (`UIImageViews`, `UILabels` and standard `UIViews`).  Some of the `UIImageViews` are partially covered by other `UIViews`.

However, when I fade out the `UIScrollView`, the partially covered parts of the `UIImageViews` are being exposed for the brief moment of the animation.

I want to be able to fade the scrollview and all it's contents at the same time in the same animation - i.e. not revealing any of the partially covered images.

If it's not possible, I can always add a `UIView` on top of all the other controls and fade it from alpha 0 upto 1 to hide everything, but I'm sure there's a way to perform a complete fade on a view and all it's subviews.

I tried this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[scrollViewResults setAlpha:0.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And I've tried this:

```
- (IBAction)questionGroupChanged:(UIButton*)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self fadeViewHierarchy:scrollViewResults toAlpha:0.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)fadeViewHierarchy:(UIView*)parentView toAlpha:(float)alpha {
    [parentView setAlpha:alpha];
    for (UIView *subView in parentView.subviews) {
        [self fadeViewHierarchy:subView toAlpha:alpha];
    }
}
```

But I've still not cracked it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because of the way the compositor works. You need to enable rasterization on the view's layer when fading it in/out:

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

You should probably only enable this for the duration of the animation because it will take up some extra memory and graphics processing time.

Comment: Also don't forget to set the proper scale, or your rasterized fades will look shitty on retina displays. view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

Answer (score 5):

Mike's answer is the correct one and he deserves all credit for this. Just to illustrate, it might look like:

```
- (void)fadeView:(UIView*)view toAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = alpha;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
                     }];
}
```

Thus, using your `scrollViewResults`, it would be invoked as:

```
[self fadeView:scrollViewResults toAlpha:0.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks for the illustration @Rob

Answer (score -2):

Did you try with UIView class methods +animateWithDuration:* (available on iOS 4 and +)

Like :

```
- (void)fadeAllViews
{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:2
     animations:^{
         for (UIView *view in allViewsToFade)
             view.alpha = 0.0;
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){}
     ];
}
```